# Where does Apache Superset Store User Queries?

Tags: linux, apache-superset

I had Apache Superset installed on an ubuntu server. A BI developer had created several dashboards in there for our company. In a chain of mistakes, the server is broken now, so we cannot start the superset server process anymore. Is there any way to rescue the "queries" that were used to create those dashboards or should all of those be re-written? Does superset store the user-defined queries in a DB or in a File/Dir on disk? If it's a DB or a file, where is it? And how can I access it and fish out those queries?

I tinkered a little with the `superset-env` folder in my home dir, but couldn't find anything useful there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a database to store the Apache Superset metadata, the database is going to depend on how you configured Apache Superset in your installation.

With the default installation in older versions of superset it was an sqllite database in `~/.superset/superset.db`, this has been probably changed with the newer versions, since sqllite is not recommended for a production installation of superset.

I don't think the organization of the database has been documented, so you'll probably have to guess yourself, with some ocassional help of a search result in starckoverflow.

Comment: Thank you. I actually found it myself. To add to this answer, you can open that db, (It's a sqlite DB by default, unless you change it), with this for example: https://sqlitebrowser.org/ and see the table named "query" for a complete history of all queries run, and the table named "tables" for all the datasets created for dashboards and charts. Hope this helps.

Comment: Also, .superset is hidden, so, ls -a to find it. This was the reason I couldn't find the damn db, otherwise I wouldn't have asked the Q in the first place!